# Modified model that generated from database first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-database-first

Beginner here

Assume that I have a model generated from the database first.

I want to manipulate that model without doing anything to that model.

How can I do that?

I thought about creating another model that related to the model generated from the database first but it is just an idea, I don't know how to do it

I would very much appreciate an answer with an example

Comment: What manipulations do you mean?

Comment: Assume that my model is about Student , Student have birthday and in Sql  datetime gonna be YYYY/MM/DD.

Because I use database first approach, I can't format birthday property in the model because it wont understand.

So that I thought about creating another model that related to the model generated from the database first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
//Get what uou need from the data
var result = context.Student
    .Where(x => x.Name) //Query the Db for what you need
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Birthday = x.Birthday.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), //Use format you need
        Name = x.Name
        //Add props you need from student
    }).ToList();
```

You can see some DateTiME FORMATS HERE https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Or if you want to use that model you can add to it ModifiedBirdday without affected the database like

```
public class Student
{
    //All student props


    [NotMapped]
    public string ModifiedBirthday => this.Birthday.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // Format you need

}
```

Comment: Helpful example

But my question is about creating a model(2) that related to the model(1) that generated by database first approach so that I whenever I want to format any property I just need to work with the model(2) to prevent conflict in database

Comment: I added a variant in which the desired format will be loaded from the base without affecting it during migrations

Comment: you have a better idea 





but 
how about my idea, can it be possible?

Comment: You can't have second model that related to the first one, the way you want.